# How should I create an SQL table with stock information so that I can add new stocks and new fields easily?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create an SQL table, where I can have any number of stocks (ie. MSFT, GOOG, IBM) and any number of fields (ie. Full Name, Sector, Country). But I want the flexibility to add new stocks and new fields as I go along. Say I want to add a new stock like AAPL, or I want a new boolean field for whether they pay dividends or not. I don't expect to store dynamic fields like CurrentStockPrice, but the information will have to change periodically. For instance, when a company changes its dividend policy. How do I design the table so that I don't have to change its structure?

I had one idea where I could have a new table for each stock, and a master table that has all the stocks, and a pointer to each individual stock's table. That way, I can freely add new stocks, and new fields easily. But I'm not very familiar with SQL, and would like an expert opinion on how it should be implemented.

Comment: Are you storing multiple records per stock? If not, then multiple tables seems like a really bad approach. Also it seems more likely that you would add more stocks than you would new attributes of stocks, so again... multiple table per stock is not a good approach. Eventually you may find that the [EAV](https://www.google.com/search?q=eav+anti-pattern) (usually an antipattern to avoid) might be the right fit if your attributes are constantly changing. If it's only changing every so often, then just `ALTER TABLE ADD...` and keep your schema simple.

Comment: No, I was thinking like this: let's say you have MSFT and GOOG. The master table has two rows, one for each, with the ticker, and a pointer to each individual stock's information table. So MSFT and GOOG each has its own fields table, where adding new fields is just adding another row. Even though the collection of stocks will change more than the number of fields, I expect to add a lot of them as my project goes along, so I want the flexibility to add them built in now.

Comment: That sounds like EAV. New "Fields", which are attributes of the stock (the A in EAV) are not stored as fields, but as rows on a stock(entity)/fieldname(attribute)/value table. It can lead to some ugly sql and some resentment from whoever adopts the mess from you, but... it also gives you enormous flexibility in design, so... it might be a good fit.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that your requirements are not a good fit for SQL. The most important concern is not how to store the data, but how you will retrieve it - what kind of query will you need to run?

EAV allows you to store data whose schema you don't know in advance - but has lots of drawbacks when querying. Even moderately complex queries (find all stocks where the dividend was paid between 1 and 12 Jan, in the tech sector, whose CEO is female) run into a lot of compexity.

Creating a new table for each type of record very quickly gets crazy too - imagine the query above if you have to search dozens or hundreds of type-specific tables.

The relational model works best when you know the schema of the information in advance.

If you don't know the schema, consider using a NoSQL solution, or use SQL Server's support for XML or JSON. Store the fixed data in rows & columns, and the variable data in XML or JSON. Performance for searching is pretty good, and it's much less convoluted as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on my comment, because the question itself begs for a couple of common schema anti-patterns. Some hybrid of EAV may actually be a good fit if you are willing to give up some flexibility and simplicity in your SQL and you aren't looking for fast queries.

### EAV

EAV, or Entity-Attribute-Value is a design where, in your case, you would have a master table of stocks with some common attributes, or maybe even ticker info with a datetime. Something like:

```
+---------+--------+--------------+
| stockid | symbol |     name     |
+---------+--------+--------------+
|       1 | goog   | Google       |
|       2 | msft   | Microsoft    |
|       3 | gpro   | GoPro        |
|       4 | xom    | Exxon Mobile |
+---------+--------+--------------+
```

And a second table (the EAV table) to store ever changing attributes:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| stockid | attribute |   value    |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 | country   | us         |
|       1 | favorite  | TRUE       |
|       1 | startyear | 2004       |
|       3 | favorite  |            |
|       3 | bobspick  | TRUE       |
|       4 | country   | us         |
|       3 | country   | us         |
|       2 | startyear | 1986       |
|       2 | employees | 18000      |
|       3 | marketcap | 1850000000 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

And perhaps a third table to get that minute by minute ticker info stored:

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
| stockid |    datetime    | value  |
+---------+----------------+--------+
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:15 | 771.41 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:14 | 771.39 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:12 | 771.37 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:10 | 771.35 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:08 | 771.33 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:06 | 771.31 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:04 | 771.29 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:15 |  56.81 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:14 |  56.82 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:12 |  56.83 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:10 |  56.84 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

Generally this is considered not great design since stitching data back together in a format like:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| stocksymbol | stockname | country | startyear | bobspick | currentvalue | 
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

causes you to write a query that is not fun to look at:

```
SELECT
    stocks.stocksymbol,
    stocks.name,
    country.value,
    bobspick.value,
    startyear.value,
    stockvalue.stockvalue   
FROM
    stocks
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT stockid, value FROM fieldsTable WHERE attribute = 'country') as country ON
        stocks.stockid = country.stockid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT stockid, value FROM fieldsTable WHERE attribute = 'Bobspick') as bobspick ON
        stocks.stockid = bobspick.stockid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT stockid, value FROM fieldsTable WHERE attribute = 'startyear') as startyear ON
        stocks.stockid = startyear.stockid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT max(value) as stockvalue, stockid FROM ticketTable GROUP BY stockid) as stockvalue ON
        stocks.stockid = stockvalue.stockid
WHERE symbol in ('goog', 'msft')
```

You can see that every "field" in the EAV table gets its own subquery, which means we read that table from storage three times. We gain the flexibility on the front end over the database design, but we lose flexibility when querying.

Imagine a more traditional schema:

```
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| stockid | symbol |     name     | country | bobspick | favorite | startyear | marketcap  | employees |
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
|       1 | goog   | Google       | us      |          | TRUE     |      2004 |            |           |
|       2 | msft   | Microsoft    |         |          |          |      1986 |            |     18000 |
|       3 | gpro   | GoPro        | us      | TRUE     |          |           | 1850000000 |           |
|       4 | xom    | Exxon Mobile | us      |          |          |           |            |           |
|         |        |              |         |          |          |           |            |           |
+---------+--------+--------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

and

```
+---------+----------------+--------+
| stockid |    datetime    | value  |
+---------+----------------+--------+
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:15 | 771.41 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:14 | 771.39 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:12 | 771.37 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:10 | 771.35 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:08 | 771.33 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:06 | 771.31 |
|       1 | 9/21/2016 8:04 | 771.29 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:15 |  56.81 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:14 |  56.82 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:12 |  56.83 |
|       2 | 9/21/2016 8:10 |  56.84 |
+---------+----------------+--------+
```

To get the same results:

```
SELECT
    stocks.stocksymbol,
    stocks.name,
    stocks.country,
    stocks.bobspick,
    stocks.startyear,
    stockvalue.stockvalue   
FROM
    stocks
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT max(value) as stockvalue, stockid FROM ticketTable GROUP BY stockid) as stockvalue ON
        stocks.stockid = stockvalue.stockid
WHERE symbol in ('goog', 'msft')
```

Now we have the flexibility in the query where we can quickly change out fields without monkeying around in subqueries, but we have to hassle our DBA every time we want to add a field.

There is a further abstraction from EAV that is definitely something to avoid. I don't know if it has a name, but I call it "Database in a database". Here you have a table of tables, table of fields, and a table of values. The entire schema is kept as records as our the values that would be stored in the schema. Ultimatele flexibility is gained, but the sql you will write to get at your data will be nightmarish and your query speeds will degrade at a fast rate as you add to your data/schema/data/schema mess.

As for your last idea of adding a new table for each stock, if the fields you are going to track for each stock are different (startyear, employees, and market cap for one stock and marketmax, country, address, yearsinbusiness in another) and you aren't planning on adding new stocks often, then it may be a good fit. I'm betting though that the attributes/fields that you track on stock1 are going to also be tracked on stock2, and therefore suggest that your should have a single stock table with all those common attributes and maybe an EAV to track attributes that are particular to each stock so you can have the flexibility you need.

In each of these schemas I would also suggest that you put your ticker data in it's own table. Whether you are capturing ticket data by the minute, hour, day, week, or month, because it's datetime level data, it deserves it's own table. (Unless you are only going to track the most current value, then it becomes a field).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add fields dynamically, but without actually altering the schema of the table, then you should use a vertical schema for the table and retrieve the data via a PIVOT statement.
In this manner you can add as many Field/Value pairs as you wish for each stock/customer pairing.

The basic table would have 5 columns perhaps:
ID (Identity); StockName; AttributeName; Value; Timestamp;

If you take a look at how SQL organizes it's table schema in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, it provides this very same vertical schema layout for you.

Comment: I thought of this, but my developer disagrees. In this case, you can't have ID as an identity because I would need one row per field with the same stock id, and he says it would get too messy with lots of stocks and fields.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree with those sentiments, though it is a genuine, tried and trusted solution to this same problem I have faced before. Unless the developer wishes to develop code that will auto-create tables for each stock, or dynamically add columns to existing tables, there are very few other approaches to take. In respect of messy, I would, respectfully disagree, but we each work in different ways, it's all good and respectful.